# Effects of the first algebraic K-theory on the higher algebraic K-theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Is there any counterexamples known to the following statement? ($A$ a regular noetherian integral domain of finite Krull dimension)

> If $A^{\times}$ is finitely generated then $K_n(A)$ is finitely generated for any $n\geq 1$

Comment: Thomason proved that every connective spectrum is the algebraic $K$-theory of some symmetric monoidal category.  Thus, if your statement is true, then it is a special feature of the symmetric monoidal categories of finitely generated projective modules over a commutative ring.  My guess is that it is false, but I don't have a strong reason for that.

Comment: The integers are a counterexample to the second statement.

Comment: Why would you ever expect those statements to be true?

Comment: It is true for fields. I wanted to know how much of good approximation fields are for integral domains coming from coordinate ring of varieties. I think using the Quillen-gersten spectral sequence or filtration as you said might help to study how much of a good approximation $K_1$ is for higher $K$.

Comment: I really doubt that $K_1(A)$ would be enough to study the finite generation of the higher K-groups. Think about how hard the Bass conjecture is, this would be reducing it to the case of $K_1$ which seems much more approachable. In general questions about the finite generation of the K-groups are really really hard...

Comment: Assume the Bass conjecture is true do you think does it imply the statement above? The statement above if true implies the Bass conjecture. Having the condition $A^{\times}$ is so restrictive for regular (which again I forgot to add it to the conditions) noetherian and of finite Krull dimension rings. I suspect that this might imply the ring is a finite type regular ring over $\mathbb{Z}$